# when we write for..of loop how does it internally call symbol.iterator

Tags: javascript, for-of-loop

Consider this code.

```
let array = [1,2,3,4,5]

for(let elem of array) {
    console.log(elem)
}
```

Since here, I am not calling anything like `array[Symbol.iterator]().since` we can only execute function by putting parenthesis after the expression that evaluates its value. here we are just writing `for(let elem of array)` how does it execute a function named `array[Symbol.iterator]` ?

Comment: `how does it internally call symbol.iterator` - the obvious answer is ... internally ... why does it matter how it's called?

Answer (score 1):

You can test it simply enough by replacing `[Symbol.iterator]` and see what happens:

```js
let array = [1,2,3,4,5]

array[Symbol.iterator] =  function* () {
    yield *['Larry', 'Mo', 'Curley'];
};

for(let elem of array) {
    console.log(elem)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice question, Actually the `for of` loop handler is mapped on `for` loop handler with a built-in iterator and parameters, for better understanding and using `[Symbol.iterator]` you can easily test it like the following code:

```
const iterable1 = new Object();

iterable1[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  yield 3;
  yield 4;
  yield 5;
};

const arr = [...iterable1];

for(let elem of arr) {
    console.log(elem);
}
```

For more information read [the Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator)

Comment: "*Actually the for of loop handler is mapped on for loop handler with a built-in iterator and parameters,*" - could you detail that please?

Comment: What does the code in your snippet have to do with the question? OP is asking about `for … of` loops, not array spread syntax.

Comment: Sure dear @Bergi, he for of loop handler is mapped on for loop handler with a built-in iterator and parameters. Hence, the `for ... of` has a regular `for` inside itself. easy.

Comment: You already said that. *How* do you think it is mapped?

Comment: @Bergi, Please don't pick on my simple word, `mapped` maybe means different things for you. I explain it before. for more information read the MDN Docs. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not picking on the word. I'm just missing an actual explanation. You say that `for … of` has an internal `for` loop, but never detail *how* this internal loop works.